# How to install node-inspector on windows 7?

Tags: node.js

I have tried a lot to install node-inspector for debug node.js code but i got a
   bunch of errors on command prompt while installing node-inspector. I am using 
   node version is 0.12.5 and npm version is 2.11.2.please guide me how to install
   node-inspector and also tell me the way for debug node.js code.

Comment: `npm install -g node-inspector`

Comment: i already installed by using npm install -g node-inspector after installed by using this i got bunch of errors ex:gyp errors..

Comment: npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "node-inspector"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! v8-profiler@5.2.11 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-buil
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-profiler@5.2.11 install script 'node-pre-gyp instal
-fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the v8-profiler package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails